# Something wrong with my validates in Rail 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show my validates in "users.rb". Can anyone help?. I've watched some video tutorial then found myself that was not "define new" but I did not know how to resolve this.

```
user_controller.rb  
class UsersController::ApplicationController  
  def login    
    if params[:user] 
      @notice   = "LOGIN FAILED"
      @email    = params[:user][:mailaddress]
      @password = params[:user][:password]
      @user     = User.find_by(mailaddress: @email)

      if @user
        @member = Member.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
        if @member
          @hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), @member.salt, @password)
          if @hash == @member.hashed_password
            # SUCCESS
            @notice = "LOGIN SUCCESSFULL"
          end
        end
      end
    end 
  end
end
-------
user.rb

class User::ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :member
  validates :mailaddress, presence: {message: "Email need inputed"} #want to show this validates in login.html.haml
end
---------------
login.html.haml

= form_for(:user, url:login_path) do |f|
  %div.login
    = f.label "Email", class:'control-label'
    = f.email_field :mailaddress, class: 'form-control'
    = f.label "Password", class: 'control-label'
    = f.password_field :password, class: 'control-label'
    %div.btn-are
      = f.submit 'Finish', class: 'btn'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validations works only on model create/update but not on some actions like login.

Please see the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) for more info.

You can show flash if some params are missing

```
user_controller.rb  
class UsersController::ApplicationController  
  def login    
    if params[:user]
      unless params[:user][:mailaddress]
        flash[:error] = "Email is required"
        render :your_login_path
      end
      @notice   = "LOGIN FAILED"
      @email    = params[:user][:mailaddress]
      @password = params[:user][:password]
      @user     = User.find_by(mailaddress: @email)

      if @user
        @member = Member.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
        if @member
          @hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), @member.salt, @password)
          if @hash == @member.hashed_password
            # SUCCESS
            @notice = "LOGIN SUCCESSFULL"
          end
        end
      end
    end 
  end
end


- flash.each do |name, msg|
  = content_tag :div, msg, class: name

= form_for(:user, url:login_path) do |f|
 %div.login
   = f.label "Email", class:'control-label'
   = f.email_field :mailaddress, class: 'form-control'
   = f.label "Password", class: 'control-label'
   = f.password_field :password, class: 'control-label'
   %div.btn-are
    = f.submit 'Finish', class: 'btn'
```

The code above is untested, but should work.

Here is the [flash documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)

But I'm strongly recommend to use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to perform sign_in/sign_up of users.

Comment: Welcome, @RyudoHalley :)